# Add row to first row in CSV file c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have small csv file where colomn headers had to be added.
One column contains the current date but also "" which is for me hard to find to remove with C#.
For example
The file contains

```
"22022016",18,39,29,84
```

It has to be:

```
A            B   C   D   E
22-02-2016  18  39  29  84
```

I tried the code below but at the ?? I had to fill a value but this is already in the second row.
Another problem is to replace "" which need I think special charaters.

Thanks in advance

```
DirectoryInfo d12 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\proef");
FileInfo[] infos12 = d12.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f12 in infos12)
{
 // #1 Read CSV File
 string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(f12.FullName);

 // #2 Split Data
 List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x =>                  
 x.Split(',').ToList()).ToList();

 //#3 Update Data
 for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
 {
 CSV[i].Insert(0, i == 0 ? "<Date>" : "Needs a value but this in the secondrom"       
 CSV[i].Insert(1, i == 0 ? "A" : "");
 CSV[i].Insert(2, i == 0 ? "B" : "");
 }

 //#4 Write CSV File
 File.WriteAllLines(f12.FullName, CSV.Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a row to begin of csv, change:

```
//#3 Update Data
 for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
 {
 CSV[i].Insert(0, i == 0 ? "<Date>" : "Needs a value but this in the secondrom"       
 CSV[i].Insert(1, i == 0 ? "A" : "");
 CSV[i].Insert(2, i == 0 ? "B" : "");
 }
```

To:

```
//#3 Update Data
 CSV.Insert(0, new List<string>{"<Date>", "A", "B"}); // 0 is index of first row
```

To modify a row:

```
int rowID = 1; // Index of row to modify
if (rowID < CSV.Count)
{
    CSV[rowID][0] = "new date";
    CSV[rowID][1] = "new A";
    CSV[rowID][2] = "new B"
}
```